# Code Academy 4/26 Javascript Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm having a great time learning about recursion (or trying to) in JavaScript, and I have done everything Code Academy has asked of me, but there's something wrong, anyway. Can anyone please (and thank you!) tell me where I have gone wrong? Code Academy is just reporting that there's an error, but it's not telling me where.

Here is my code, and I have pasted the instructions below it.

```
function multiplyBy10(number) {
  console.log(number * 10);
}

function multiplesOf10(limit) {
   for(i=1;i==limit;i++){
    multiplyBy10(i);
   }
}

multiplesOf10(100);
```

Instructions:

Complete the definition of `multiplesOf10()` by adding a for loop.

The for loop should start with `i = 1` and end when `i` is equal to the value of limit.

Within the for loop, call the function `multiplyBy10()` and pass it the variable `i` as an argument.

Finally, call the function `multiplesOf10()` at the end of your code, passing any integer you like as an argument.

Comment: Well, do you get the output you'd expect from caling your function with `100`? Hint: there's something wrong with your loop.

Comment: …and btw, this has absolutely nothing to do with recursion.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Code Academy told me to make i 'equal to' the variable limit, and I took them at their word, even though my instincts told  me to say '<='. Thank you for the hint. It works  now!

Comment: recursion is a function that calls that same function over-and-over , hopefully stopping at one point..

Comment: It is not a recursion. You call another function `i` times, when a recursion means that you call the same function inside this function.

Answer (score 1):

In the instruction I found that **loop should start with i = 1 and end when i is equal to the value of limit** But your condition is 
   `for(i=1;i==limit;i++)` which would be false all time . So You need to change your condition .
Here's the right one :

```
for(i=1;i<=limit;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an example of recursion , probably it's not the answer to your problem but you might understand how it work (the comments in the code are the explanation of what's happening):

```js
 array = [];  //this array is going to be populated by one entry each time we call the function 
function multiplesOf10(limit) {

 
  if (limit == 0 ){return array}//this is the end point or recusion and will return the array with results
  
  array.unshift(10*limit);//will add the entry to beginning of array
  
  return multiplesOf10(limit-1);//recursion
  
}

console.log(multiplesOf10(10));
```